# В чем разница в вызове function() и вызове function без "()"?

Tags: javascript, функции

Мне необходимо использовать метод replace для строки. В документации https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace
есть пример кода:

```
function replacer(match, p1, p2, p3, offset, string) {
  // p1 - не цифры, p2 - цифры, p3 - не буквы и не цифры
  return [p1, p2, p3].join(' - ');
}
var newString = 'abc12345#$*%'.replace(/([^\d]*)(\d*)([^\w]*)/, replacer);
```

Мы видим что функция `replacer` вызвана без параметров, хотя в определении самой функции она принимает их! Как это понимать?
Я написал нечто похожее на пример из документации:

```
const regExpression = /(\s+[a-z])/g;
let strTrimAfterReplace = strTrim.replace(regExpression, replacer);

function replacer(match){
  return match.toUpperCase()
}
```

И у меня функция не вызывается вообще! Объясните пожалуйста что я не понимаю или в какой раздел документации смотреть.

Comment: В том, что второе (без скобок) это не вызов функции.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский у меня в коде там console.log, но консоль пуста и значение переменной `strTrimAfterReplace ` - undefined.

Comment: @Vitaliy во-первых у тебя регулярка другая, а во-вторых  у тебя strTrim undefined.....если подставить данные из первого примера - то всё работает нормально

Comment: @AlexeyTen но ведь в коде из документации используется синтаксис без скобок и все работает.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ja2bgsdq/

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я могу дать листинг всего кода. Вот что выдает console.log().
`str: a
strTrim: a
strTrimAfterReplace: a`
Функция не вызвалась.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский спасибо за пример! Попробую подать на вход строку с пробелами между слов. Ведь моя регулярка ищет пробелы... Скорее всего проблема в этом. Но это не объясняет главного! Почему мы вызываем replacer и не передаем туда параметры?

Comment: @Vitaliy Насчёт вызова без параметров. Это не вызов, а только передача функции. Вызывается она потом внутри метода replace. То же самое происходит например в методе forEach у массивов. Это называется колбэк. То есть функцию можно передавать туда-сюда без вызова, а потом вызвать где-то, круглыми скобками обычно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var newString = 'abc12345#$*%'.replace(/([^\d]*)(\d*)([^\w]*)/, replacer);
                               ^^^^^^^                          ^^^^^^^^
```

В вашем коде происходит вызов только одной функции - `replace`, при этом ей в качестве второго параметра передаётся *ссылка* на функцию `replacer`. После чего вызов функции `replacer` делается уже внутри функции `replace` (не вами).

А если бы вы тут указали `replacer` со скобками как `replacer(...)`, то да - вы бы тогда *сразу* вызвали эту функцию, а вот функция `replace` получила бы уже не ссылку на `replacer` и возможность её вызвать, а *результат работы* функции `replacer`, вызванной с теми аргументами, которые *вы* ей при этом передали.

Но в данном контексте требуется именно *ссылка* на функцию, чтобы та функция, которая получает эту ссылку, могла сама вызвать эту функцию по ссылке в тот момент и с теми аргументами, с которыми она посчитает нужным её вызвать. Это очень удобный механизм, широко используемый в программировании и в частности в `JavaScript`.